# Solving migrate error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

This is the error I get:

QueryException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nerd_level' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `nerd_level`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (dasda, vincentnelissen@hotmail.nl, 1, 2017-04-05 19:16:42, 2017-04-05 19:16:42))

I've searched for an answer why this happends and I need to migrate they say. However when I try to do that I get this error:

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre
  ady exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_incr
  ement primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not n
  ull, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null,
  `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `nerd_level` int
  not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

```
                                                                             [PDOException]
```

SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre
  ady exists

Could anyone invest a little time to help me please?

Vincent

Comment: What does your migration look like?

Comment: Here is a repo of what I think you are doing.... https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-nerds

Answer (score 0):

The users table already exists but your migrations table doesn't have a record of it being migrated.

To solve this issue:

1. Export any data from your `users` table you
   want to keep.
2. Comment out the `up()` method in your migration.
3. Run the migration `php artisan migrate`. This way the migration will
   be recorded as being completed. Rollback the migration `php artisan
   migrate:rollback`. This runs the `down()` method, dropping the users
   table.
4. Uncomment the `up()` method.
5. Run the migration again `php artisan migrate`.
6. Import `users` data from step 1 if you want.